# Tab delimited file with different number of columns - R

Tags: r, readr, csv

I got a large, tab delimited csv-file (10,000,000 rows). It supposed contain 11 different columns with lab values (test number, test date, test type, test unit, value, additional text, etc.)

Using `readr::read_tsv` throws an error:

```
read_tsv("file_name.csv")
```

Error:

```
Warning: 90486 parsing failures.
row col   expected    actual    file
9213391  -- 11 columns 8 columns 'file_name.csv'
9213392  -- 11 columns 4 columns 'file_name.csv'
9217859  -- 11 columns 1 columns 'file_name.csv'
9217860  -- 11 columns 4 columns 'file_name.csv'
```

Found a couple of solutions for more columns than expected but not for this problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Does `data.table::fread` work better?

Comment: Even if it throws a warning, It will return a dataframe with missing values in the appropriate places. Is there anything else you want it to do?

Comment: `data.table::fread("file_name.csv", fill = TRUE)` does the job without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Those are warnings, not errors.  `read_tsv` still gives a result and if that result is `DF` then `attr(DF, "problems")` describes the problem rows.

For example, to remove the problem rows:

```
DF <- read_tsv("file_name.tsv")
problems <- attr(DF, "problems")
if (!is.null(problems)) DF <- DF[-problems$row, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems. I think the reason we have this problem is that some observations are seprated into two lines for some reason.

Deleting these observations may be a solution. But I think if the warning is caused by the above reason, correcting by combining them into one line may be a better solution since as you see, you have 90486 warnings.